# PySpark - How to pass a list to User Define Function?

Tags: list, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have a DataFrame with 2 columns. Column 1 is "code" which can repeat more than 1 time and column 2 which is "Values". For example, column 1 is 1,1,1,5,5 and Column 2 is 15,18,24,38,41. What I want to do is first sort by the 2 columns `( df.sort("code","Values") )` and then do a `("groupBy" "Code")` and (agg Values) but I want to apply a `UDF` on values so I need to pass the "Values" of each code as a "list" to the `UDF`. I am not sure how many "Values" each Code will have. As you can see in this example "Code" 1 has 3 values and "Code" 5 has 2 Values. So for each "Code" I need to pass all the "Values" of that "Code" as a list to the `UDF`.

Comment: It is highly recommended to not use udf's if it's possible. They can slow down the computation time by a lot in some cases.
That's why i would always try to keep using the native spark implementation. If you tell us, what your UDF does, we can maybe help to find a way to do it.

Comment: Please upvote the below answer if found to be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `groupBy` and then use the `collect_set` or `collect_list` function in pyspark. Below is an example dataframe of your use case (I hope this is what are you referring to ):

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext


sc = SparkContext("local")

sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    ("code1", "val1"),
    ("code1", "val2"),
    ("code1", "val3"),
    ("code2", "val1"),
    ("code2", "val2"),
], ["code", "val"])

df.show()
```

```
    +-----+-----+
    | code| val |
    +-----+-----+
    |code1|val1 |
    |code1|val2 |
    |code1|val3 |
    |code2|val1 |
    |code2|val2 |
    +---+-------+
```

Now the `groupBy` and `collect_list` command:

```
(df
  .groupby("code")
  .agg(F.collect_list("val"))
  .show())
```

Output:

```
+------+------------------+
|code  |collect_list(val) |
+------+------------------+
|code1 |[val1, val2, val3]|
|code2 |[val1, val2]      |
+------+------------------+
```

Here above you get list of aggregated values in second column

Comment: In PySpark I used this one and it works            df.groupBy("Code").agg({"val":"collect_list"}).show()                        Thank you so much @ashwin agrawal for your help

Comment: Please upvote the answer and select answer to be right.